# MySQL Fulltext Search on Multi Tables

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine

I have 2 tables:

```
"product_info" table:
id     name           price
==========================
1      LG Monitor     $250


"product_detail_info" table:
id    product_info_id    detail_title    title_position      content
========================================================================
1     1                  Features        2                   bla bla bla
2     1                  Specification   1                   bla bla bla
```

How can I link both 2 tables data together for searching in mysql fulltext search and have the result returned to be the name of the product on "product_info" table?

Thanks.

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts into one. You can now edit your question or leave comments under individual answers. I would have converted your 'answers' to comments, but I could not tell which one was intended for what answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql full text search functionality will give what you want - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html. You'll just need to have your table set up correctly for it.

```
SELECT product_info.name FROM product_info 
LEFT JOIN product_detail_info 
ON product_info.id = product_detail_info.product_info_id
WHERE MATCH ( content ) AGAINST ( your_search_string )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But how can I write the match(content) for 2 tables? 
I tried to write it as below and it returned with error:
match (product_info.name, product_info.price, product_detail_info.detail_title, product_detail_info.content)

Comment: Read through the docs I've linked, you will need to create a `FULLTEXT` index on the fields you want to `MATCH` against before you can query them, and it only applies to CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

Comment: Yes, I do know the need to create fulltext indexes. But how to write for the "MATCH (content)" in the query? If only one table, it can be written in "MATCH(name, price)". How to write it for 2 tables? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  pi.name
FROM
  product_info pi
  INNER JOIN product_detail_info pdi ON pdi.product_info_id = pi.id
WHERE
  pdi.content MATCH <your condition>
```